# Prove this matrix is neither unipotent nor nilpotent.

Tags: linear-algebra

The question asks me to prove that the matrix,

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

is neither unipotent nor nilpotent. However, can't I simply row reduce this to the identity matrix:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

which shows that it clearly is unipotent since $A^k=I$ for all $k \in \Bbb Z^+$?

Is there something wrong with the question or should I treat A as the first matrix rather than reducing it (I don't see how it would then not be unipotent considering the two matrices here are equivalent)?

Comment: $A$ is unipotent, since $(A-I)^2= 0$.

Comment: Also, row reduction doesn't mean that you can always reduce a matrix to the identity matrix. For example, if you start with the 0 matrix, then you can only get the 0 matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: As Calvin Lin pointed out in the comments, $(A-I)^2=0$, so $A$ is unipotent. To show that $A$ is not nilpotent, show by induction on $n$ that

$$A^n=\begin{bmatrix}1 & n\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\;.$$

Answer (score 2):

Or more easily, determinant of A is nonzero so it can not be nilpotent.